# HTML:Image won’t display

Tags: image

My image won’t display for no reason. I am a noob but I can’t figure it out. The image loads from the url so I know it’s not that. So I’m pretty sure it’s my problem with the coding.

```html
<body>
    <img src=https://www.dropbox.com/s/rm27v6s4nj885qu/IMG_0071.PNG?dl=0
    Height=300Width=250>
</body>
```

Comment: You're missing a space between 300 and Width.

Comment: URL does not return image it returns a dropbox page that contains image; you need a URL that returns image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is pointing to non-image resource. It's actually pointing to an HTML document.

In URL, change `www` by `dl` and remove `?dl=0`.
This is valid image URL :

```
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/rm27v6s4nj885qu/IMG_0071.PNG
```

Alternatively, you can replace `dl=0` to `raw=1`. This is also valid image URL:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rm27v6s4nj885qu/IMG_0071.PNG?raw=1
```

Not always required but as a good practice I'll suggest using quotes for values. Also as mentioned in comments seperate attributes from each other with white space.

```html
<img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/rm27v6s4nj885qu/IMG_0071.PNG"
height="300" width="250"/>

<!--OR-->

<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/rm27v6s4nj885qu/IMG_0071.PNG?raw=1" height="300" width"250"/>
```

source : [Mickel's Tutorial](https://code.sololearn.com/WW6t4B73kJVz/)

Answer (score 1):

I hope, you must use the url of image, But you are referring the url preview pane of dropbox.

It is the actual url for image.

You also need some improvisation with your code, as below

```html
<body>
  <img src="https://uc215f04ebb05efbc98d874fefb2.previews.dropboxusercontent.com/p/thumb/AA767gGwgVfZ9rVS7PJbtIOR3eQsWN4mrXjNjVJH3JKjhI5eE7JOd-eQJwydUx1gPkpE3zkAnMSN3-1KEtFN86x-CdWnREg0mQ6hm7APBCuifux1ECDivRuLkrikn1sY_r20EmBWucKHyy-Ps5VPB8ehkUB6x0y9kSb3QzYpP8fOo7IeyR6IaCYZ66mxrJiUiUtzTAV3ddESpRV7lSRaumsSyVPc4k1RbUBS3-_JDnP8Qv6M42x2g7bZDy9vdhhIOZaO585_XQHegapCJ-8bnwLGt-VEy9nud0avi_gzMSpXxx3EXt_NYTWMfFqfstb2HFMVb7WK7jxkSRSX5eE5ck3Q0bdEPAKp1aPnClU2KqI-OgUea6ApGp4G0H4Q3l3UyOjfomtn-SndAAaUzPbaU1HK/p.png?fv_content=true&size_mode=5" height="300" width="250" />
</body>
```

It will work without any issue. You are not **referring proper url** that the actual issue.

Also, keep tag properties in quote "" if required.

Like

```html
<img src="url" height="200" width="300" />
```

Thanks.